# how to prevent trigger the onclick function on <tr> when I do focus on my input inside of the <tr> element?

Tags: javascript

```js
function focusInputFunction(event){
  console.log("focus");
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

function clickTr(){
  console.log("tr");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="clickTr()">
    <td>
      <input id="myInput" onfocus="focusInputFunction(event)"type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want that when I focus on my text field, the event `click` on the `<tr>` element is not executed.

I just want to execute the focus event on my text field and not fire the click event on the `<tr>.`

How can I do this?

Comment: I've added the answer for that but I don't understand why will you add the click event in the first place, if you don't want it fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the "click" event<sup>✥</sup> by registering a common ancestor element of `<tr>` and `<input>` and then have the event handler<sup>❉</sup>  do nothing should the `<input>` be `:focused`.

In the example below we have a `<table>` with two `<tbody>`s of which the second one is hidden. Whenever the user clicks the `<table>` or one of it's children elements, the second `<tbody>` is revealed/hidden. If the `<input>` is `:focused` on, the previously mentioned behavior does not happen.

<sup>✥ See [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).</sup>

<sup>In the example, `<table>` is registered to the "click" event but `<tr>` would work as well.</sup>

<sup>❉ An event handler is basically a function that is called when a registered event is triggered.</sup>

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Reference the common ancestor of <tr> and <input>
const ancestorNode = document.querySelector("table");

// Reference the <input>
const focalPoint = document.querySelector("input");

// Register the "click" event to <table>
ancestorNode.onclick = delegateClick;

// "click" event handler passes the (event) Object by default
function delegateClick(event) {

  // Reference the element user is focused on
  const focused = document.activeElement;
  
  // If the user IS NOT focused on <input>...
  if (focused !== focalPoint) {
  
    //...add/remove ".show" from <tbody class="hidden">
    document.querySelector(".hidden").classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

// A simple event hadler to show <input> is focused on
focalPoint.onfocus = e => console.log("Active element is <input>");
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody {
  float: left;
}

td {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  width: 4.5rem;
  font: inherit;
}

.hidden {
  width: 0;
  visibility: collapse;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.show {
  width: 10rem;
  visibility: visible;
}

.as-console-row::after { width: 0; font-size: 0; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; word-break: break-word; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; max-width: 50%; margin-left: 50%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input placeholder="Enter text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="hidden">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.stopPropagation();`  only stops the propogation to parent for the focus event. the click event will still be fired. Add it to `click` event on input. Check code below.

```js
function focusInputFunction(event) {
  console.log("focus");
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function clickTr() {
  console.log("tr");
}

function clickinput(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="clickTr()">
    <td>
      <input id="myInput" onclick="clickinput(event)" onfocus="focusInputFunction(event)" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with bubbling events, you can use [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to check where the event originated from.

```js
function focusInputFunction(event) {
  console.log("focus");
  //you won't need these lines for this, uncomment if you need them for something else
  //event.stopPropagation();
  //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

function clickTr(event) {
  if (event.target.id === "myInput") {
    return;
  }
  console.log("tr");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="clickTr(event)">
    <td>
      <input id="myInput" onfocus="focusInputFunction(event)" type="text">
    </td>
    <td> other content in tr (to test onclick)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```